# Javascript - Can the 'import' keyword be used to import css?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I may be a bit confused here but is there an equivelent of

`require('../css/mystyles.css')`

for the `import` command?

i.e:
`import '../css/mystyles.css`

If no, why not?

## Context:

Using webpack with vue and hoping to load css files in a manner consistent with the modules

Comment: Webpack just needs a CSS loader to handle it. If you're using a Vue CLI v3 project, it should work out of the box

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Comment: Thanks @Phil wow you are right It does work out of the box with Vue CLI v3 surprisingly. VSCode wan't autocompleting file imports like it normally does, so I thought it wouldn't work but was surprised to find it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You certainly can import css files with the `import` statement like this:

```js
import "../css/mystyles.css.css"
```

In the `webpack.config.js` file you should add a rule to use ‘css-loader’ and ‘style-loader’ for .css files:

```
module.exports = {
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader']
            }
       ]
    }
```

Check out this [article](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/webpack-loaders-css-and-sass-2cc0079b5b3a) on Webpack loaders. It's very clear.

Answer (score 0):

From ES6 onwards we can use **import** keyword

For webpack configuration refer to the official doc [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) , you will get the exact figure from there